# Dynamic VirtualHost and DocumentRoot and ServerName

Tags: windows, apache, wamp, virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *.laravel:80>
    DocumentRoot "z:\wamp\www\laravel\%1\public"
    ServerName %1.laravel
</VirtualHost>
```

This does not work. What I'm trying to do here is have the documentroot of `http://*.laravel/` be `z:\wamp\www\laravel\(wildcard * value here)\public`

I don't know how to get the value of the wildcard. My windows `hosts` file is setup correctly to point to localhost

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to use `VitualDocumentRoot` instead of `DocumentRoot`
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#virtualdocumentroot

Also, `ServerName` is always static (all your dynamic DocumentRoots will have the same exact ServerName). It's one of the problems with dynamic VHs.